# How to create a hypothesis test comparing two odds?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, odds

Let's say I have two odds, how would I conduct a hypothesis test with a 5% significance level?

Comment: Do you have the original data or only the odds?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have the original data.

Comment: What are your null and alternative hypotheses?

Comment: @Dave I am trying to test where the odds of developing cancer are the same for two groups, when one group is exposed to radiation and the other is not. So I assume my null hypothesis would be it wouldn't be the same? I am not sure.

Comment: I think that is a reasonable null hypothesis. Now why do you want to test odds instead of probability?

Comment: @Dave As the question I am doing requires to do it for odds. So how would I structure this and what calculations would I do?

Comment: I would convert the odds to probabilities and use any of the numerous proportion tests like “prop.test” in R. Since this is a self-study question, please add the self-study tag and read its wiki. If converting to probability from odds does not satisfy the requirements of your homework problem, please explain why not. Posting the entire question (verbatim) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, your exposure (radiation) and outcome (cancer) are binary which means we can use a bunch of tools to analyze the odds.  Luckily, there is a lot of theory to help us out.

We usually write out contingency tables for these studies.  They may look like

```
           Radiation    No Radiation
Cancer     a            b
No Cancer  c            d
```

Asymptotically, the distribution of the log odds ratio is normal.  So we can use a variation of the z test and use the variance under the null (assuming the risk in each group is the same)

$$ \dfrac{\log(\widehat{OR}) - \log(OR)}{\sqrt{V(\log({OR}))}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

Here, $\log(\widehat{OR})$ is the log of the estimated log odds ratio, and $\log(OR)$ is the log odds ratio under the null hypothesis.  The variance of the log odds ratio under the null has a very easy expression

$$ V(\log({OR})) =  \dfrac{a+b+c+d}{p(1-p)(a+c)(b+d)} $$

Here, $p$ is your estimate of the prevalence of the outcome which is assumed to be the same in both groups (so just take the number of people who got the outcome and divide by the total sample size to estimate $p$).

For more, chapter 2 of [Biostatistical Methods](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470907412) is dedicated to exactly this.

## Example

```
           Radiation    No Radiation
Cancer     53            40
No Cancer  47            60
```

My null hypothesis would be that each group has the same risk of cancer.  My estimate of the risk for cancer would be $(53+40)/(53+40+47+60) = 93/200 = 0.465$

The odds ratio for this problem is $1.69 = (53 \cdot 60)/(47 \cdot 40)$, and so my log odds ratio is$\log(\widehat{OR}) = 0.52$.

The variance of the log odds ratio is 0.08, using the formula above.

If each group has the same risk of cancer, then that means $OR=1$ or $\log(OR)=0$.  My test is then

$$H0: \log(OR)=0$$

$$HA: \log(OR) \neq 0$$

$$z = \dfrac{0.52-0}{\sqrt{0.08}} = 1.85$$

Which would fail to reject the null with a p value just shy of 0.05.

Comment: That makes great sense! Thank you so much.