# How do I conduct a hypothesis test based on the Crime Rate Benchmark for determining racial bias applied in police stop and search

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am currently conducting an analysis on Racial Bias in UK Stop and Search. I would like to test whether there exists bias based on the "Crime Rate Benchmark" method. This method represents comparing the search rate of an ethnicity to its crime rate, and if there is no significant difference, then there is no bias applied. This is something like the "External Benchmark" method which is based on comparing the search rate and population rate of the ethnicity. For example: Blacks represent ~13% of the U.S. population; if Blacks represent more than ~13% of U.S. citizens searched,
this is taken as evidence of racial disparity. Such a calculation
answers the question: “given the population proportions of
each race, are Blacks more likely to be searched than
Whites?”.

I am interested whether it is possible to make some kind of hypothesis test like a Chi-square test for Homogeneity for this crime rate benchmark method. [This paper](https://osf.io/ycrsm/download) does it via the Crime Rate Benchmark way (page 5 - multiverse analysis). For example, if I do a Chi-squared test on a different racial-bias-determining method like Hit rates (amount of stops which resulted in having some kind of legal action taken over the whole amount of stops), it would be to test the hypothesis whether the Hit Rates for Whites are the same as Hit Rates for Blacks (basically comparing the odds, [like this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467615/how-to-create-a-hypothesis-test-comparing-two-odds)). But if I have the crime rates of White and Blacks with Search rates of Whites and Blacks, how do I conduct a hypothesis test? I am confused since it's not possible to create a table like in the linked question, since if we'd compare hit rates, it would be something like :$$H_0: \frac{\text{Number Black people hits}}{\text{Total Number of Black people searched}} = \frac{\text{Number of White people hits}}{\text{Total number of White people searched}}$$

But with the Crime rate benchmark test, how would we statistically determine bias? How would you build a mathematical/statistical model with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "Crime Rate Benchmark method", seams easily feasible with a Chi squared test.

Given a sample of all the searches made in a certain period, you can compare the proportions of the etnicities of the searched with the official crime rates for those etinicities. It's called [goodness of fit chi-squared test](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/statistics-knowledge-portal/chi-square-test/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test.html).

However, I suspect it's a very difficult task to gather a representative sample of all searches for any country. And in lack of that, hypothesis testing is not the most appropriate tool for the analysis.